# What types of WiFi does the iPod touch 4th generation use?

Tags: ipod-touch

I am buying a router.  But it says 2.4 GHz is that not that great.  So I want to know if it supports.  Just curious what types of WiFi it supports: A, B, G, and/or N.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [specifications](http://support.apple.com/kb/SP594), the fourth generation iPod touch supports 802.11b/g/n on the 2.4GHz band.

The first through third generations support 802.11b/g, while the fifth generation supports 802.11a/b/g/n on both the 2.4 and 5GHz bands.